# Devise, admin_mailer & config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I'm using devise with my rails 4 app.

I'm trying to setup figaro before I let the site go live, but for now, I'm managing my test email account with my passwords in production.rb. It won't be this way for long, but I have hit a problem with my setup.

I have two admin_mailer emails that get sent when someone registers. One is an email to me, using one gmail account to let me know that they have registered. The second is an email to the user, welcoming them to the site. It is supposed to be sent from a second email account that I set up.

In my production.rb, I have:

```
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 ###,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            'firstemailaddress@gmail.com',
    password:             '###',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }

     {
      address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
      port:                 ###,
      domain:               'gmail.com',
      user_name:            'secondemailaddress@gmail.com',
      password:             '####',
      authentication:       'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

In my admin_mailer, I set the sender for the emails as one or the other of those user names.

However, when I run the code, both emails are sent from the first email address.

Does anyone know how to set up to mailers so that emails send from different addresses?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think each mailer is supposed to be associated with one email account. You could create two separate mailers, and define the smtp settings within each individual mailer rather than in production.rb.

For example, app/mailers/first_mailer.rb :

```
class FirstMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'firstemailaddress@gmail.com'
  self.delivery_method = :smtp
  self.smtp_settings = {
    # your gmail smtp settings here
  }

  def some_email(user)
    mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Subject')
  end
end
```

You can send this by calling `FirstMailer.some_email(user).deliver`.

Similarly, you then create another file app/mailers/second_mailer.rb that uses a different account (and so different settings).

There may be a more DRY way to do this, but I know this works.